# Unknown error in if statement

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, command, raspbian

I get an *Unknown error* in the `if` statement in my bash script:

### Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
DAY=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
LUDAY=$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")
LUTIME=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
mkdir /home/pi/Documents/Webcam/Shots/$DAY
fswebcam -d v4l2:/dev/video0 -r 1720x1280 --no-banner /home/pi/Documents/Webcam/Shots/$DAY/$TIMESTAMP.jpg /home/pi/Documents/Webcam/Shots/Live/Live.jpg
sudo cp /home/pi/Documents/Webcam/Shots/$DAY/$TIMESTAMP.jpg /usr/share/apache2/icons/Live.jpg
timesincelastmod=$(expr $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r /var/www/html/index.html))
declare -i delay=10
TIMESINCELASTMOD=$(($timesincelastmod+0))
if [$TIMESINCELASTMOD \< $delay]; then
  sed -i -e "s|\(Lastupdate:\).*\(.\)|\1 $LUDAY at $LUTIME (CEST) \2|g" /var/www/html/index.html
else
  sed -i -e "s|\((CEST)\).*\(.\)|\1 - (Failed to upload last photo) \2|g" /var/www/html/index.html
fi
```

### Error :

```
pi@JayRasp:/usr/lib/apache2/modules $ sudo bash /home/pi/Documents/Webcam/update_pic.sh
--- Opening v4l2:/dev/video0...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Adjusting resolution from 1720x1280 to 1600x1200.
--- Capturing frame...
Captured frame in 0.00 seconds.
--- Processing captured image...
Disabling banner.
Writing JPEG image to '/home/pi/Documents/Webcam/Shots/2016-07-07/2016-07-07_0659.jpg'.
Writing JPEG image to '/home/pi/Documents/Webcam/Shots/Live/Live.jpg'.
/home/pi/Documents/Webcam/update_pic.sh: line 13: [1805: command not found
```

Comment: Put a space after `[` and before `]` on the line `if [$TIMESINCELASTMOD`...

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is your friend, kindly check your script there for all the syntax issues.

Comment: This is undoubtedly a duplicate; there are a **lot** of questions solved by adding spaces before and after `[` and `]`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah it probably is, but I didn't know what to search for because I didn't know what the issue was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need spaces around your `[` and `]`.

Why?

`[` is a command.

```
tim@Hairy16:~$ ls /usr/bin
[
```

Try `if [ $TIMESINCELASTMOD \< $delay ]; then`

In bash, commands need spaces around them.

Also, you need to use `-lt`, `-gt`, `-le` and `-ge` instead of the `\` before a `<` or `>`. they mean *Less Than*, *Greater Than*, *Less than or Equal to* and *Greater than or Equal to*.

Comment: Thank you, solved the problem, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @JoshuaWeber If you can, please accept this answer to show the question is solved!

Comment: @JoshuaWeber click the tick below the down arrow.

Comment: Done! Have a nice day Sir.

Comment: @JoshuaWeber: Actually, if I understand what the script is doing, you *must* use `-le`, `-gt`, etc, because they do numeric rather than lexical comparisons. The difference is that `[ 5 -lt 100 ]` is true, but `[ 5 \< 100 ]` is false because "5" comes before "1" in lexical sorting order. Either that, or use double-parentheses expressions (e.g. `(( TIMESINCELASTMOD < delay ))`), which are entirely arithmetic (and auto-expand variables, and don't require escaping the greater- and less-than signs).